# Expression of basis vectors of permutation modules in different bases.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Write $[n]:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For a partition $\lambda\vdash n$, I will write $[\lambda]$ for the Specht module that corresponds to $\lambda$, i.e. the complex vector space spanned by all standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$.

Consider the complex vector space $V_k$ which has as a basis the $k$-element subsets of $[n]$. The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on $V_k$ in the was that $g\in S_n$ maps a basis vector $A\subseteq[n]$ to the basis vector $g(A)=\{ g(i) \mid i\in A \}$. Let us assume $k\le \frac n2$. It is known that 
$$V_k = \bigoplus_{j=0}^k~ [n-j,j]$$
is the decomposition of $V_k$ into irreducibles. See, for instance, Example 7.18.8 in Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics* (Volume 2).

**Question:** Given any $j\le\frac n2$ and a standard tableau $T$ of shape $\lambda=(n-j,j)$, I would like to know how to express the corresponding basis vector $v_T$ of $[\lambda]$ in the canonical basis of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$.

**Thoughts:** For $k=1$, this is rather easy. For the only standard tableau $T$ on $\lambda=(n)$, the vector $v_T=\sum_{i=1}^n \{ i \}$ is just the sum of all $1$-element subsets of $[n]$. On the other hand, for a standard tableau $T$ of $(n-1,1)$, let $a_T$ be the number in the single box in row $2$. Then it can be checked that $v_T=\{1\}-\{a_T\}$. However, I already have trouble with $V_2$. There is an obvious $S_n$-invariant inclusion
\begin{align*}
\phi_1: V_1 &\longrightarrow V_2 \\
\{i\} &\longmapsto \sum_{j\ne i} \{ i,j \}
\end{align*}
and the $[n-2,2]\subseteq V_2$ must be isomorphic to $V_2/\mathrm{im}(\phi_1)$, but I didn't get much further.

I very much believe that this should be covered in a basic textbook somewhere: I did not find any. I would be tremendously grateful if anyone could recommend a good reference.

Comment: I do not know much about two-part partition of Specht modules and the related combinatorics result, but have you tried Humphrey's Young Tableaux book?  I know some people do give particular attension to two-part partition, namely Mathas, Lyle, and Fayers.  I doubt if their works are written in any textbooks, and it is quite possible the results you want are buried in their papers which study more general Specht modules...

Comment: @Aaron: Do you mean Fulton's book? I didn't find anything on permutation modules in there. I am unaware of a book by Humphreys on Young Tableaux.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, it's Fulton's...

Comment: I [cross-posted this at mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130075/expression-of-basis-vectors-of-permutation-modules-in-different-bases).